# Show a function is monotonically decreasing.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Show that $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

I'm trying to show that $f'(x)\leq0$ to show it's monotonically decreasing.  So $f'(x)=\dfrac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$.   I can see that $f'(x)\leq0$ but having trouble proving it.

Answer (score 4):

We have using the formula for the derivative of a quotient
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}
$$
Then we can use the fact that on $[0,\pi/2]$
$$
\tan(x)\ge x\qquad\text{and}\qquad\cos(x)\ge0
$$
See $(1)$ or $(4)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151).

Answer (score 3):

To show $f'(x)\lt 0$ in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$, it is enough to show that $g(x)\lt 0$ in the interval, where $g(x)=x\cos x-\sin x$.

Note that $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=-x\sin x$. Thus $g(x)$ is decreasing in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$, indeed all the way to $\pi$. It follows that $g(x)\lt 0$ in our interval.